# Reduce blank space in moderncv template

Tags: templates, moderncv

I would like to know how I can reduce the blank space after the title in the moderncv latex template, look at the picture below :

[image]

**EDIT :**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=0.3cm, bottom=1.0cm, left=1.2cm, right=1.2cm]{geometry}
% Largeur de la colonne pour les dates
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.5cm}
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{20}{20}\mdseries\upshape}

\address{X}{X}{X}    
\email{X}                      
%\homepage{X}
\mobile{X} 
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\makecvhead}{%
\usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}\fi%
\\[2.5em]%
}{%
\usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}\fi%
\\[1em]%
}{}{}
%% add the following additionally
\xpatchcmd{\makecvhead}{\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}{%
\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[1em]}{}{}
\extrainfo{X}
\firstname{X}
\familyname{X} 
\title{X} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use `quote`:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\name{The name}{}
\title{Some title}
\address{address\\address\\address\\}
\phone[mobile]{123456789}
%\quote{some quote here}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\makecvhead}{%
  \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}\fi%
  \\[2.5em]%
  }{%
  \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}\fi%
  \\[1em]%                   %%% change 1em to anything you like
  }{}{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Formations}

\end{document}
```

If you use `quote`:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\name{The name}{}
\title{Some title}
\address{address\\address\\address\\}
\phone[mobile]{123456789}
\quote{some quote here}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\makecvhead}{%
  \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}\fi%
  \\[2.5em]%
  }{%
  \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}\fi%
  \\[1em]%
  }{}{}
%% add the following additionally
\xpatchcmd{\makecvhead}{\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}{%
  \quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[1em]}{}{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Formations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry I tried to add the code you proposed but it still doesn't work, I probably made a mistake (I'm very new to latex), please check my last edit.

Comment: @otus This works for the latest version of `moderncv`. Please check and update.

Comment: How can I update it ? i'm using a code given by a friend on this website : https://fr.sharelatex.com/

Comment: @otus: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: Just `\xpatchcmd{\makecvhead}{\\[2.5em]}{\\}{}{}` also works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another easier solution is to put `\vspace*{-1cm}` after `\maketitle`.

[source](https://answers.launchpad.net/moderncv/+question/213724)